# What is a shortcut for a nested if greater than function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

`=IF(Z2>=CU25,CV25,IF(Z2>=CU24,CV24,IF(Z2>=CU23,CV23,IF(Z2>=CU22,CV22,IF(Z2>=CU21,CV21,IF(Z2>=CU20,CV20,IF(Z2>=CU19,CV19,IF(Z2>=CU18,CV18,IF(Z2>=CU17,CV17,IF(Z2>=CU16,CV16,IF(Z2>=CU15,CV15,IF(Z2>=CU14,CV14,IF(Z2>=CU13,CV13,IF(Z2>=CU12,CV12,IF(Z2>=CU11,CV11,IF(Z2>=CU10,CV10,IF(Z2>=CU9,CV9,IF(Z2>=CU8,CV8,IF(Z2>=CU7,CV7,IF(Z2>=CU6,CV6,IF(Z2>=CU5,CV5,IF(Z2>=CU4,CV4,CV3))))))))))))))))))))))`

Is there a better way to write this function in excel? The processing is slow because there are so many if functions nested. Basically I am comparing Z2 to values in CU to put it into groups defined in CV.

Comment: An example of your data would be helpful, along with an explanation of what you have, and an example of what you're trying to accomplish.  As-is, I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense.  It's seems kind of like you're looking for the "last" value in a column.

Comment: Might be able to do it with `INDEX` `MATCH`

Comment: hlookup horizontal lookup.

Comment: seems like `=LookUp(Z2, CU3:CV25)`

Answer (score 0):

Nested greater than lookup in excel

```
=VLOOKUP(Z2,CU8:CV25,2,1)
```

Comment: No vlookup is verticle.  I actually made a sheet with a lookup to simulate the vc25 vc24 vc23 ..  the OP was using.

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish the same thing, but it will *evaluate* slower since it will compare `Z2` to all of `C4:C25` instead of stopping when one of the conditions returns `TRUE` (enter as an array formula, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CV4:CV25,MAX(IF(Z2>=CU4:CU25,ROW(CU4:CU25)))-ROW(CU4)+1),CV3)
```